# How do I rename the column 0 in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. How do I give the first column a name?

[image]

I tried using `dplyr` but it doesn't work.

```
colnames(df)[0] <- "Test"
```

Comment: R is 1-indexed. The first column is column 1

Comment: Please do not add data as images. Use `dput` instead.

Comment: @Dason I tried that but it doesn't work. It will just change that 3/31/2019 column to Test

Comment: Try this but you should really use `rename/mutate` since you tagged `dplyr`: `names(df)<-replace(names(df),1,"test")` Actually your question now seems to be about more of  a `reshape2`ing.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a column, those are the row names. Within the tidyverse there's a function to create a column out of them:

```
 df<-tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "test")
```